# xConnect in a non-sitecore context interaction lifetime

Tags: xconnect

I am making a demo application with the new xConnect.
I've got a .NET Core application that acts as a cash register to add experience data to xConnect.

Now i've come to the point that i want to add an interaction with some events.
However i'm not sure how long to keep these interactions alive. I can't send the Interaction to xConnect after the first event because i won't be able to change it again.
Would it be best practice to save the Interaction in a cookie until all events are added or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How does session relate to your real-world scenario (cash register) that you're trying to model? Wouldn't you want to save an xConnect interaction as soon as cash register operation is completed?

Comment: Maybe the cash register is a bad example, but i've got multiple events like "enter store", "add item to cart", "checkout'. I'd like to have those in one interaction

Comment: Web interaction has a clearly defined lifetime - it's completed when web session expires. What about interactions that you're creating? What's their lifetime? If you are trying to model "session" in a physical store, then you need to know what triggers interaction start and interaction end. Is that done by store's staff, beacon, etc? For demo purposes I think it's fine to use Sitecore's Tracker and force web session to complete (e.g. by clicking a button) instead of waiting for it to expire.

Comment: Okay, the checkout button would be the end of the line for the interaction.
The last thing i was contemplating about is where to save the Interaction inbetween events. Because i have a .NET Core application i would have to send the entire Interaction to a Cookie because the controller that creates the Interaction gets disposed. (would saving a json it in a cookie be the best way?)

Comment: You can still use SessionState in asp.net mvc core by referencing a nuget package: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/38033.asp-net-core-and-mvc-core-session-state.aspx Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks i'm saving my interaction in a session until i'm done with it now

Comment: Great! I will compose an answer from the comments above. Feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web interaction have a clearly defined lifetime - it's completed when web session expires. What about interactions that you're creating? What's their lifetime? If you are trying to model "a session" in a physical store, then you need to know what triggers the interaction start and the interaction end. Is that done by store's staff, beacon, etc? For demo purposes I think it's fine to use Asp .Net session to store interaction until it's considered finished and then save it to xConnect.

Session can be used for Asp.Net Core by referencing *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session* package. Detailed description can be found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/38033.asp-net-core-and-mvc-core-session-state.aspx).